# php-fpm dead but subsys locked

Tags: php

When I check the status of php-fpm then it says

**php-fpm dead but subsys locked**

Why it is not showing  status running or dead only?

How to solve this ?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/26276/what-does-service-name-dead-but-subsys-locked-mean